# Connection closed with error KeepAliveTimeout

Tags: parachain, error

I'm developing my own client using `libp2p` to connect to a `substrate-based parachain` (in this case I'm testing with moonbeam/moonriver).

However, my client gets disconnected after a while with this error:

```
2022-11-29 17:04:02.095 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker libp2p_swarm: [] Connection closed with error KeepAliveTimeout: Connected { endpoint: Listener { local_addr: "/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/30333", send_back_addr: "/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/9999" }, peer_id: PeerId("12D3Koo...") }; Total (peer): 1.
2022-11-29 17:04:02.095 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker sub-libp2p: [] Libp2p => Disconnected(12D3Koo..., SetId(0), ConnectionId(136)): Enabled.
2022-11-29 17:04:02.095 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker sub-libp2p: [] Libp2p => Disconnected(12D3Koo..., SetId(1), ConnectionId(136)): Enabled.
2022-11-29 17:04:02.095 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker sub-libp2p: [] Libp2p => Disconnected(PeerId("12D3Koo..."), Some(KeepAliveTimeout))
```

This then lowers my score and so on. I'd like to know what possible reasons are there to get this error so that I can try to fix them on my client.

Comment: when you connect, do you follow light client protocol flow? if now, may be node logic is to kick connection which does not follow protocol

Comment: @DzmitryLahoda our node tries to act as a full node, our score is always 0 (perfect score) according to a real substrate node

Comment: do you send ping or something within short period to node?